# Windows 10 Errors when trying to reinstall default apps via Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I see lots of default windows Apps such as Camera, Microsoft Store, Cortana missing on my Windows 10 Pro PC. After searching on internet I found the following command fixes it.

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml”}
```

But when I tried to run it, it throws error

> Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073D02, The
> package could not be installed because resources it modifies are
> currently in use. error 0x80073D02: Unable to install because the
> following apps need to be closed
> MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_120.2212.3920.0_x64__cw5n1h2txyewy. NOTE:
> For additional information, look for [ActivityId]
> 37fe793e-0191-0005-7386-fe379101d801 in the Event Log or use the
> command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID
> 37fe793e-0191-0005-7386-fe379101d801

what is this file MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_120.2212.3920.0_x64__cw5n1h2txyewy and how would I disable/stop it.

I don't want to reset the PC as will waster hours of my time getting everything back.

Thanks
X

Comment: Can you try it immediately after a reboot?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that. Also tried clean reboot by disabling all services and startup programs. None worked. Wondering  what this file is MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_120.2212.3920.0_x64__cw5n1h2txyewy

Answer (score 1):

I found this package on my own system here:

```
C:\Windows\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy.
```

Please read [this](https://oofhours.com/2021/01/27/digging-into-the-windows-feature-experience-pack/) for some more information. It will show that it's an `AppxPackage` and can thus be removed. Considering the overview at the end on that site it seems you won't miss it anyway, but can nevertheless reinstall after you've finished reinstalling your Windows apps.

Another solution might be to reinstall the apps individually like so:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
$packages =@(
"Microsoft.549981C3F5F10" # Cortana
"Microsoft.BingWeather"
"Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller"
"Microsoft.GetHelp"
"Microsoft.Getstarted"
# "Microsoft.HEIFImageExtension"
"Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer"
# etc.
)

ForEach ($packages in $packages){
Get-AppxPackage -Name $packages -AllUsers|Add-AppxPackage
}
Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue resolved after killing **TextInputHost** process, which seems to be part of the `Client.CBS` package.

```
Get-Process TextInputHost | Stop-Process
```

This allowed me to run the `Get-AppXPackage` command without errors.